# How to Convert Single Record to Multiple Records in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a Oracle database with thousands of records of customers who have taken services from us. A sample service table(simplified) having list of services we provide looks like following:

```
Service Table
------------------------------------
| id | service_code | name | price |
------------------------------------
|  1 |     101      |  abc |   20  |
|  2 |     102      |  xyz |   20  |
------------------------------------
```

Above is a simplied table from the database. Here some of the services (each record reprensents a service) are individual and some are group of two services (that are supposed to given always as a set/group).

**Problem:** 
Let suppose service with id 2 is a group of two services. We need to print a invoice for it showing entry of both services individually. I need a `SELECT` a query for that.

```
Invoice Example:
    ---------------------------------
    | service_code |  name  | price |
    ---------------------------------
    |     102A     |  xyz_A |   15  |
    |     102B     |  xyz_B |   05  |
    ---------------------------------
```

I know using Oracle case statement I can change values like this:

```
SELECT 
CASE id WHEN 2 THEN '102A'
END AS 'service_code'
CASE id WHEN 2 THEN 'xyz_A'
END AS 'name'
CASE id WHEN 2 THEN 15
END AS 'price'
FROM customers;
```

(I know there will be multiple `when` in case statement for each service code)

Hope you understood my problem. ***Now the issue is what about second sub-service? How to get that? Is there any way for that?***

```
second sub service => |     102B     |  xyz_B |   05  |
```

Comment: Forgot to mention: I will be using that query to generate Crystal report.

Comment: Can you clarify the question by showing an example of your source data where you have multiple services under the same ID? I'm presuming your problem is more complex than Select * from service_table where ID=2 ?

Comment: @iainc We have a another table customer, both table have primary-foriegn relationship. Each customer record have id(foreign key) of service he has taken from us. But now we need to print invoice describing sub-services for group service. (I know this was a mistake, we ignored such scenario while designing database structure few years back). But now we need a solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT service_code, name, price FROM service where service_code not in (102/* set of grouped services */)
union
SELECT service_code || 'A', name || '_A', price-5 FROM service where service_code in (102/* set of grouped services */)
union
SELECT service_code || 'B', name || '_B', price-15 FROM service where service_code in (102/* set of grouped services */);
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this will work for us. I will surely try this tomorrow morning, if works I will accept your answer.